# Python Scrapy Login and Crawl Multiple Pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working on creating a script to crawl kenpom.com to capture college basketball statistics. I have become better at Python and Scrapy largely due to the community on Stack Overflow. Thank you very much!

I have been able to successfully login to the site via scrapy but I am not able to figure out how to login and then scrape multiple pages. It appears that the script is attempting to login everytime it hits a new page.

What changes do I have to make in order to login, select pages to crawl via date range, and then scrape the desired data?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my Spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from datetime import timedelta, date

class KenpomeffSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kenpomeff'
    allowed_domains = ['kenpom.com']
    start_urls = ['https://kenpom.com/']

    def login(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                         formdata={'password': 'xxx',
                                                   'email': 'xxx@gmail.com'},
                                         callback=self.date_range)
    
    def daterange(start_date, end_date):
        for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
            yield start_date + timedelta(n)
            
    start_date = date(2020, 11, 25)
    end_date = date(2020, 12, 2)
    start_urls = []
    start_url='https://kenpom.com/archive.php?d='
    
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        start_urls.append(single_date.strftime(start_url+"%Y-%m-%d"))
                
            
    def parse(self, response):
```

Output:

```
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.3.0 started (bot: kenpom)
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 3.0, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'kenpom',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'kenpom.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['kenpom.spiders']}
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 500ce7baaae78688
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['kenpom.pipelines.KenpomPipeline']
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kenpom.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> from <GET https://kenpom.com/archive.php?d=2020-11-25>
2020-12-02 12:00:28 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> (referer: None)
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> from <GET https://kenpom.com/archive.php?d=2020-11-26>
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> from <GET https://kenpom.com/archive.php?d=2020-11-27>
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> from <GET https://kenpom.com/archive.php?d=2020-11-28>
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> from <GET https://kenpom.com/archive.php?d=2020-11-30>
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> from <GET https://kenpom.com/archive.php?d=2020-11-29>
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> from <GET https://kenpom.com/archive.php?d=2020-12-01>
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> (referer: None)
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> (referer: None)
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> (referer: None)
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> (referer: None)
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> (referer: None)
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1> (referer: None)
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 4322,
 'downloader/request_count': 15,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 15,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 124755,
 'downloader/response_count': 15,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 8,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 7,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.494702,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 2, 18, 0, 29, 208958),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 15,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 8,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 14,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 14,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 14,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 14,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 2, 18, 0, 28, 714256)}
2020-12-02 12:00:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no login in your code at all (according to your debug output). Try this version:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

class KenpomeffSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kenpomeff'
    allowed_domains = ['kenpom.com']
    start_urls = ['https://kenpom.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response=response,
            formid="login",
            formdata={
                'password': 'xxx',
                'email': 'xxx@gmail.com'
            },
            callback=self.check_login,
        )
    
    def check_login(self, response):
        # here you better need to check login success
        # like:
        # if response.xpath('//some/element/on/success/login/page'):
            
        start_date = date(2020, 11, 25)
        end_date = date(2020, 12, 2)
        start_urls = []
        start_url='https://kenpom.com/archive.php?d='
        
        for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=start_url + single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                callback=self.parse_date,
            )
                
            
    def parse_date(self, response):
        ...
```

Comment: How it is possible to check `response.xpath()` within `check_login(start_date, end_date)` as I can see no `response` parameter within that method @gangabass? Would be glad if you could clarify a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry! My typo, of course it should be `def check_login(self, response):`